# Layout Scrollable horizontal

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
 i found this code for making my layout scrollable. But how can i do the same thing when my layout is horizontal?

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"> //I change it here to horizontal but no result
              <!-- Content here -->
        </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Use `HorizontalScrollView`

Comment: use `HorizontalScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` and secondly dont use `fill_parent` its depricated use `match_parent`

Comment: In xamarin doesnt support HorizontalScrollView (I think)

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this:

       //add view of linear_Pmains to Linnearlayout of your layout
       HorizontalScrollView scollview = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
        View v2 = null;
        LinearLayout linear_pmains = new LinearLayout(this);
        linear_pmains.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        lsellerbooks.removeAllViews();
        // Do ur functionality     
        scollview.addView(linear_pmains);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the xml file way (definitely better!) this is how it works:

```
       <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/somelayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

      </HorizontalScrollView>
```

You don't need to use "LinearLayout" but since it is a ScrollView, it can only hold one child. So there has to some kind of Layout inside.